# Update a docker image

Tags: r, dockerfile, docker-image

I want to use the docker image at this GitHub URL (https://github.com/weizhou0/GATE); there was a bug in the script (https://github.com/weizhou0/GATE/blob/main/R/SAIGE_SPATest.R) that has been fixed, but the docker image file appears to have not been updated, as I continue receiving that error (Now fixed the error X1_fg %*% Z : non-conformable argument). I only want to know how to change the Docker image file to benefit the corrected script (https://github.com/weizhou0/GATE/commit/b098153d0b7f43abd8e1dec1cbabf7b8e7e5430a)

When I use the commands below I receive the script with the bug.

```
docker pull wzhou88/saige.survival:0.45
docker save -o saige_1.1.9.tar.gz wzhou88/saige.survival:0.45
chmod a+r saige.survival_0.45.tar.gz
```

I want people to advise me on how to update the docker image file.